# ONVIF Authentication in .NET 4.0 with Visual Studios 2010

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ws-security, onvif

My task is to try to establish a communication with a ONVIF camera in the building to, eventually, upgrade the company's domotic solution to automatically recognize ONVIF cameras and to be able to set them up and to use their services.

I am already able to gather some basic informations like its model, its MAC address and its firmware version this way:

```
    EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("<mycameraurl:<mycameraport>/onvif/device_service");
    CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding("DeviceBinding");
    DeviceClient temp = new DeviceClient(bind, endPointAddress);
    String[] arrayString = new String[4];
    String res = temp.GetDeviceInformation(out arrayString[0], out arrayString[1], out arrayString[2], out  arrayString[3]);
    MessageBox.Show("Model " + arrayString[0] + ", FirmwareVersion " + arrayString[1] + ", SerialNumber " + arrayString[2] + ", HardwareId " + arrayString[3]);
```

I have this xml specification for the customBinding in my app.config file:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="DeviceBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
          messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          keepAliveEnabled="false" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

My problem is that it's impossible for me to go deeper into what I can ask the camera. I get "400 - Bad request" errors for anything I try, and according to what I have read it's because I need to handle authentication for the camera.

The problem is that, everything I find about WS-Security (which seems to be used by the ONVIF) is really, really confused, with a lot of different solutions, and nothing really working for me. For example, [this post here](http://custforum.axis.com/viewtopic.php?p=4522&sid=7990ea009d57544606efd627f3a40541)  make it sound very simple, but I've tried to create a UserNameSecurityToken and I still get 400 bad request errors. Since I don't know if that's because I've written my Token system wrong, if it's because the camera doesn't support what I try to do.

I've already tried WSHttpBinding and putting it in Username mode, but using WSHttpBinding break the basic information discovery I was able to create (with a MustUnderstand error)...

Any pointers for me? Simple WS-Security/.NET, C#/ONVIF tutorials, everything will be accepted.

Comment: This is a side note...The fact you seem to indicate that you are new to C# and you were able to get this far is impressive.

Comment: Well i've done JAVA for years, and in the end it's definitively easier than some years ago, now you can usually find little code snippets on the internet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All right:

```
EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress("<mycameraurl:<mycameraport>/onvif/device_service");

HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

httpBinding.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;

var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();

messageElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);

CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messageElement, httpBinding);

// Add our custom behavior - this require the Microsoft WSE 3.0 SDK

PasswordDigestBehavior behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(CameraASCIIStringLogin, CameraASCIIStringPassword);

DeviceClient client = new DeviceClient(bind, serviceAddress);

client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

// We can now ask for information

client.GetSystemDateAndTime();

client.GetNetworkInterfaces();

client.GetScopes();

client.GetRelayOutputs();

client.GetWsdlUrl();
```

The problem was that the camera required authentication before giving any information beyond the simplest ones, and the trickiest part was to finally catch a working xml onvif message to recreate it in my own software.

Comment: For those not familiar with PasswordDigestBehavior, see this blog post: http://blog.benpowell.co.uk/2010/11/supporting-ws-i-basic-profile-password.html