# Defining DeviceClient(Bind, endPointAddress)

Tags: c#, wsdl, onvif

I am trying to interface with **ONVIF** certified equipment, like being able to access simple device information.

I have been trying to use the following code, provided by another member here:

[ONVIF Authentication in .NET 4.0 with Visual Studios 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638247/onvif-authentication-in-net-4-0-with-visual-studios-2010)

However, am having trouble understanding what the function **DeviceClient** is and what it does.
I have tried to find it on the **ONVIF WSDLs** and as a class, but with no avail.
Am very new to **C#**, **WSDLs** and **ONVIF**, and as such appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with similar issue when my code was unable to recognize `DeviceClient` and `MediaClient` classes. From Hugo's comments I got the clue and removed OnVif references from my C# project which I'd already added as Web References. Then simply added following references as Service References and it worked for me:

1. http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl
2. http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

Below is the working code snippet I took from another post on StackOverflow.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://" + cameraAddress + "/onvif/device_service");
var httpTransportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement { AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest };
var textMessageEncodingBinding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None) };
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(textMessageEncodingBinding, httpTransportBinding);
var passwordDigestBehavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(adminName, adminPassword);
var deviceClient = new DeviceClient(customBinding, endPointAddress);
deviceClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(passwordDigestBehavior);
```

Answer (score 2):

I convert devicemngmnt.wsdl file to .cs file using vs2010 command promt but codefile does not contain "deviceclient".
Also I tried to add your xml snippet to .wsdl file and when I triy to convert .wsdl to .cs file by using VS2010 command prompt I get this error.

Error: Unable to import binding 'DeviceBinding' from namespace 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl'.

- Unable to import operation 'GetServices'.
- The datatype 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema:OnvifVersion' is missing.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head several times I finally realized my problem.

I had to add a service to the wsdl, in the format:

```
   <wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
     <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>
     </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

After that it was just a matter of adding it to the project as a Service Reference, instead of a Web Reference. After that the library picked up the DeviceClient(Bind, endPoint) reference.

Hope this helps people out.