# OnVif integration error - unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Digest'

Tags: c#, ip-camera, digest-authentication, onvif

Using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918196/369383) to connect to OnVif service on my IP Camera in C# .Net 4.5.
Very next to that code, I am trying to get Device information as follows:

```
string str = client.GetDeviceInformation(out model, out firmware, out serial, out hardwareId);
```

And encouters this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Digest'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="CBBA"'.
```

I tried [this information about Basic realm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.whatsnew.doc/cws_security/dfhe4_realm.html). By adding an Http header `WWW-Authenticate` to the request with value `Basic realm="Our Site"`. But no luck.

What the heck is that? How to fix it?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably failing to handle the [Digest Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication). To handle things correctly, you should send a request to a not `PRE_AUTH` ONVIF method without using authentication, neither digest nor ws-usernameToken.

You can get one of the two following answers:

1. you get a 500 response with `env:Sender ter:NoAuthorized` which means that the camera does not support HTTP digest (which in fact, for profile S devices is not mandatory). In this case you have to use only WS-UsernameToken
2. you get a 401 response with the `WWW-Authenticate` header from the device. In this case you should follow the [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), evaluate all the necessary elements and resend your requests with the `Authorization` header.

Remember that an HTTP digest challange is always started by the camera, you can't just add it to the first request.

Check §5.12 of the [Core specification](http://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v241.pdf), at least to know has a camera handles authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [relevant issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170475/onvif-soap-request-with-soap-level-authentication-and-http-authentication) - I had to authenticate with ONVIF cameras for which I did not know the authentication HTTP authentication modes (Basic/Digest). In my answer you can see how to properly iterate through all the HTTP authentication schemes or you can just take the code for Digest, hope it helps.