# ONVIF c# - set osd or camera title

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I'm new into ONVIF. I made connection with camera's webservice and I can ask for some data from camera ( I used method described here : [ONVIF Authentication in .NET 4.0 with Visual Studios 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638247/onvif-authentication-in-net-4-0-with-visual-studios-2010) ) . I also can ask for information from Media webservice. Unfortunately when I call GetOSDs() or CreateOSD() methods I get "Optional Action Not Implemented" exception. GetVideoSourceConfigurations() method is working so I assume that my handler to Media webservice is OK and those methods are really not implemented, but in desktop software provided with camera by manufacter I can modify OSDs so that application somehow receive this data, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. My code:

```
EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.64/onvif/device_service");
EndpointAddress mediaAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.64/onvif/Media");

HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

httpBinding.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;

var messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();

messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);

CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, httpBinding);

        // Add our custom behavior - this require the Microsoft WSE 3.0 SDK
PasswordDigestBehavior behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior("admin", "12345");
MediaClient media = new MediaClient(bind, mediaAddress);
DeviceClient client = new DeviceClient(bind, serviceAddress);

client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
media.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

        // We can now ask informations
var date = client.GetSystemDateAndTime(); // OK
var configs = media.GetVideoSourceConfigurations(); // OK
var osds = media.GetOSDs(configs.ElementAt(0).token); // exception Optional Method Not Implemented
var osds2 = media.GetOSDs(""); // exception Optional Method Not Implemented
```

My goal is to programmatically set some overlay text on screen every 2 seconds. It can be OSD, it can be name, but it must be later visible on record. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look with a packet sniffer what the differences are between your application and the vendors software. I suspect they are not using ONVIF to edit the OSDs.

Answer (score 0):

Onvif OSD implementation is optional and most manufactures did not implement it.

They just check if their camera survives the Onvif Device Test tool which is not testing the OSD.

Although the cameras do have other ways to check and configure OSD texts. Typically there is an other REST interface which is not based on Onvif.